# SQL - insert into table if value exists in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am trying to get the sql query below to work but I am getting an error, my problem is as follows:

I need to loop through a results set from a select statement (this part is fine).  Inside the loop for each row I need to check if the URL exists in tableA.  If it does then insert a mapping into tableB, otherwise insert a new row into tableC.

This is what I have but when I try to execute I get an error on the line with the IF saying ORA-06550: line 8, column 15:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:( - + case mod new no.....

```
DECLARE 
STANDARD_LINK_ID TABLEB.LINK_ID%type;

BEGIN   
      FOR LINK_ROW IN ( SELECT LINKTEXT, LINKURL, CORPID FROM OLD_DATA)
      LOOP
          IF (SELECT COUNT(URL) FROM TABLEA WHERE URL = LINK_ROW.LINKURL) = 1
          THEN
            SELECT LINKID INTO STANDARD_LINK_ID FROM TABLEA WHERE URL = LINK_ROW.URL;
            INSERT INTO TABLEB(LINK_ID, CORP_ID) 
            VALUES (STANDARD_LINK_ID,  LINK_ROW.CORPID);
          ELSE
            INSERT INTO TABLEB(LINK_ID, LINK_NAME, URL, CORP_ID) 
            VALUES (SEQ_LINK.NEXTVAL, LINK_ROW.LINKTEXT, LINK_ROW.LINKURL, 
                                 LINK_ROW.CORP_ID);
          END IF;                 
      END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen it done this way; but not the select with return value embeded in the condition

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=177035

```
DECLARE 
STANDARD_LINK_ID TABLEB.LINK_ID%type;
DECLARE W_LINK_COUNT NUMBER (1,0);

BEGIN   
      FOR LINK_ROW IN ( SELECT LINKTEXT, LINKURL, CORPID FROM OLD_DATA)
      LOOP
          SELECT COUNT(URL) INTO W_LINK_COUNT FROM TABLEA WHERE URL = LINK_ROW.LINKURL;
          IF  W_LINK_COUNT = 1
          THEN
            SELECT LINKID INTO STANDARD_LINK_ID FROM TABLEA WHERE URL = LINK_ROW.URL;
            INSERT INTO TABLEB(LINK_ID, CORP_ID) 
            VALUES (STANDARD_LINK_ID,  LINK_ROW.CORPID);
          ELSE
            INSERT INTO TABLEB(LINK_ID, LINK_NAME, URL, CORP_ID) 
            VALUES (SEQ_LINK.NEXTVAL, LINK_ROW.LINKTEXT, LINK_ROW.LINKURL, 
                                 LINK_ROW.CORP_ID);
          END IF;                 
      END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your if statement is the culprit, because what you are trying to achieve should definitely be possible. Can you please try the following instead:

```
DECLARE 
STANDARD_LINK_ID TABLEB.LINK_ID%type;
URL_COUNT NUMBER(10);

BEGIN   
      FOR LINK_ROW IN ( SELECT LINKTEXT, LINKURL, CORPID FROM OLD_DATA)
      LOOP
          SELECT COUNT(URL) INTO URL_COUNT FROM TABLEA WHERE URL = LINK_ROW.LINKURL;
          IF URL_COUNT = 1 THEN
            SELECT LINKID INTO STANDARD_LINK_ID FROM TABLEA WHERE URL = LINK_ROW.URL;
            INSERT INTO TABLEB(LINK_ID, CORP_ID) 
            VALUES (STANDARD_LINK_ID,  LINK_ROW.CORPID);
          ELSE
            INSERT INTO TABLEB(LINK_ID, LINK_NAME, URL, CORP_ID) 
            VALUES (SEQ_LINK.NEXTVAL, LINK_ROW.LINKTEXT, LINK_ROW.LINKURL, 
                                 LINK_ROW.CORP_ID);
          END IF;                 
      END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Hope it helps you figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I've written it really quick, but I think that this two queries will solve your problem without loop (which is slower then one time insert):

```
-- insert to tableb when exists in tablea
insert into tableb(link_id, corp_id) 
select a.linkid, o.corpid
from old_data o
join tablea a on o.url = a.url


-- insert to tablec when not exists in tablea
insert into tablec(link_id, link_name, url, corp_id) 
select seq_link.nextval, o.linktext, o.linkurl, o.corp_id
from old_data o
where not exists(select 1 from tablea a where o.url = a.url)
```

ps. don't you forget about `tablec` in `else`?

Comment: Now I'm from a different world but if it's like in my world set operations is much faster than loops. Don't know if that's true for oracle too so please feel free to enlighten me

Comment: I think that `loop` in an SQL world is some kind of evil especially when there is way to do it using result sets with many records in one hit (as in this case).

Comment: +1 I agree that performance and avoidance of loops is generally a good thing.

Comment: in this case the query is just being used to copy data once so thankfully performance isn't an issue